# Can't use conda/miniforge on apple silicon

Tags: python, conda, apple-m1

I have an issue with conda Miniforge , I can't activate conda environment on my MacBook Pro silicon. I used the [tutorial](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) in GitHub but it seems that there is no garanties that will works for apple m1 .

I got this log in my console :

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/myuser/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 140, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "/Users/myuser/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 1210, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
      File "/Users/myuser/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 178, in execute
        return getattr(self, self.command)()
      File "/Users/myuser/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 152, in activate
        builder_result = self.build_activate(self.env_name_or_prefix)
      File "/Users/myuser/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 300, in build_activate
        return self._build_activate_stack(env_name_or_prefix, False)
      File "/Users/myuser/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 326, in _build_activate_stack
        conda_prompt_modifier = self._prompt_modifier(prefix, conda_default_env)
      File "/Users/myuser/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 691, in _prompt_modifier
        return context.env_prompt.format(
    KeyError: 'venv'

`$ /Users/myuser/miniforge3/bin/conda shell.posix activate base`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_EXE=/Users/myuser/miniforge3/bin/conda
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/Users/myuser/miniforge3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/Users/myuser/miniforge3
              CONDA_SHLVL=0
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                 INFOPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/info:
                  MANPATH=/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/opt/X11/share/man:/opt/homebrew/s
                          hare/man
                     PATH=/Users/myuser/miniforge3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/s
                          bin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/myuser/mini
                          forge3/condabin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /Users/myuser/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/myuser/miniforge3/.condarc
                          /Users/myuser/.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=11.5.2=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=arm64
       base environment : /Users/myuser/miniforge3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/myuser/miniforge3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /Users/myuser/miniforge3/pkgs
                          /Users/myuser/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/myuser/miniforge3/envs
                          /Users/myuser/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-arm64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.9.6 Darwin/20.6.0 OSX/11.5.2
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

no

No report sent. To permanently opt-out, use
```

I tried to install python 3.9 using brew install etc and its working 100% . But now  I need to create virtual environment for each project.

Comment: What command did you attempt to run?

Comment: Conda can't activate base environment ```conda activate base```

Comment: This looks related to PS1 prompt modification. Do you have any special PS1 defined? What shell are you using? Does it work to run the command `conda shell.posix activate base` directly?